How to position a floating widget behind an opened section without altering the section's properties?
I have a floating widget on my webpage, and there's a specific section that opens when a button is clicked. When the section opens, the widget overlaps with a button inside the opened section.
I want the floating widget to move behind the opened section when it's displayed, without changing any properties of the section itself.
How can I achieve this using HTML and CSS?
What I tried:
I attempted to adjust the z-index of the floating widget to a lower value than the opened section. For example:
#floating-widget {
   z-index: 1;
}
    
#opened-section {
   z-index: 1600000; /* ( don't change anything from it) */
}

I also tried setting the position of the opened section to relative and the widget to fixed to see if it would naturally place the widget behind the section.
What I expected:
I expected the floating widget to appear behind the opened section without affecting its behavior or placement.
What actually happened:
The floating widget remains on top of the section, overlapping the button inside the opened section. It seems like the widget's z-index isn't being overridden or respected properly.

Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. To help you with your issue, we do need some code to reproduce it and to see what you have tried.
Create a minimal reproducible code snippet

It would be helpful if you could share a reproducible example.

Please add your HTML code.

You probably cannot use z-index because the "section" and the "widget" are part of different stacking contexts. The order of the elements in the HTML can also be important. For a real answer you need to post the code so we can see where the problem is.
